# How to use git describe on a detached head commit?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a main branch that has annotated-non-lightweight-tagged commits in it.
The workspace is in a detached head state, i.e. after checked out via [Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin)

When I run `git describe` I am getting the name of a really old tag, together with a very high number of commits since that tag, (e.g. `1.0.0-459-abc1234`)

When I run `git tag` I get a list of all tags, including the most recent ones, that I am interested in, e.g. `3.1.0`, `3.2.0`.

I was then thinking about doing something like `git branch -r --contains HEAD` to get the name of the remote branch, then fetch and check that out (Running the risk that I am actually checking out a later commit than the one that triggered the pipeline, but whatever, it's isolated to a pull request anyways...)
Or just run `git describe <remote_branch_name>`
But neither of that worked.
I don't understand why Git would prefer to show the very old tag instead of more recent ones, since any pull request is branched off the tag-containing `master` branch (every commit that had been tagged is guaranteed to be found on the `master` branch).

Comment: If you follow your current (detached) HEAD commit (ie its parent, parent-parent, etc), do you find a commit with a tag 3.x.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem might have been different git version actually. One host had a rather old git version installed (1.7.x) after upgrading to 2.10.x everywhere, the problem went away.
Another possible reason could be that we sometimes updated tags, pointing them to a new commit (we stopped doing that.)
I noticed at one point, that when you create a lightweight tag, and then change it to a annotated tag, another client that had already seen the lightweight tag, will not download the updated, now annotated tag, when you do `git fetch --tags`, because it recognizes it had already seen the tag by name, and does not bother that the type of the tag has changed, therefore `git describe` will not pick up that tag for that client.